# How to add matchers in Python unittest.TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
datastructure = {
     frame:"test"
     position:
          {
           x: 1,
           y: 2,
          }
     orientation:
          {
           w: 1.23,
           z: 2.24,
          }
}
```

I have custom datastructure. I need to do an `assertAlmostEqual(a, b)`. However the above datastructure does not have a `- (subtract)` operator overloaded and therefore  `assertAlmostEqual` does not work

Can I write matchers in `unittest.TestCase` like in gmock [matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#matchers).
For example I would like to write a custom version of `assertAlmostEqualCustom`

Comment: What is your condition for almost equality then?

Comment: my condition is they should not differ by 0.02 however ```assertAlmostEqual``` does not work because the datastructure cannot be subtracted

Comment: Since your data structure is a dictionary, you can implement a supplementary function that calculates the required quantity, so you can pass function's return value to assertAlmostEqual.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I write matchers in unittest.TestCase like in gmock matchers?

Sure you can, many projects have already using their own `YourTestCase` inherited from `unittest.TestCase`, e.g. `class TestDataStrut(YourTestCase)` will be used instead of `class TestDataStruct(unittest.TestCase)`.

If you have to use the specific assert often in a large project, you have to do it yourself.

[Django TestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/)

[Django testcases.py code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py)

[An Example of creating your own TestCase](https://gist.github.com/horvatha/2e11b48f431c53b101db6cb817b2fc7f)